# PhpStorm and JavaScript: how to get full doc support

Tags: javascript, ide, phpstorm, javascript-intellisense

I use `PhpStorm 2017.1.4` IDE. When I code in PHP, the core functions are all documented in the IDE (beyond just the parameters, I can see what the function does etc..)

[image]

I'm now practicing my JavaScript. Although the IDE knows the core functions, there is no documentation:

[image]

So find myself always going on [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to learn about functions, which really slows down my work. How can I shore up my IDE to provide fuller documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Quick documentation popup opened on `F1` (or `Ctrl+Q`) shows information written in comments attached to object in `.js` file object is defined in (`plugins\JavaScriptLanguage\lib\JavaScriptLanguage.jar!\com\intellij\lang\javascript\index\predefined\EcmaScript.js` in your case). You can create a copy of this file somewhere on your disk, add more doc comments to functions stubs, and add this modified file as a JavaScript library to your project

If you like to see full API docs, hit `Shift+F1`, or press blue 'up' arrow button in documentation popup toolbar (note that this function is only available for libraries that have 'documentation URL' configured)

[image]
See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.2/viewing-inline-documentation.html